# Swift - Circle progress, start at different positions with same iOS versions

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit

I've create a simple circle progress and upload [code here](http://pastebin.com/UvNPUbNg)

I have problem that circle progress starts at different points on different devices.

[image: iPhone 6]

[image: iPhone 4S]

First one is correct and is from iPhone 6 and second one is taken from iPhone 4S and I would like that it starts at up. Both where tried with iOS 9.3 so where could be problem?

I guess probably below (maybe in line with creating transform) but I am not sure how to fix it. Can anyone help?

```
  func circlePath() -> UIBezierPath {
    let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(ConversionFunctions.DegreesToRadians(-90))
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: circleFrame())
    bezierPath.applyTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-self.frame.width / 2, -self.frame.height / 2))
    bezierPath.applyTransform(transform)
    bezierPath.applyTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height / 2))
    return bezierPath
  }
```

Comment: Do you see this problem on a real iPhone 4S or only on the simulator?

Comment: Yes, it's on real iPhone 4S too but I don't have it. I find it because one of the test users told me about this.

Comment: I reproduced the problem on the simulator too.  It is a very odd bug, but it seems to be Apple's problem. `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(ConversionFunctions.DegreesToRadians(-89.99999))` doesn't have the issue.  Similarly `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI_2))` does but `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI_2)+0.00001)` doesn't

Comment: the iPhone 5 simulator exhibits the same issue, so it seems to be a 32 bit issue